# Compiler C to Brainfuck (for harassing a professor)?

Tags: c, decompiler, brainfuck

A professor of mine has said he'll accept homework assignments in any language we'd care to use.  I'm on good enough terms that I'd like to mess with him a bit and submit a valid homework assignment using brainfuck, whitespace, or some equally "useful" language.

I have the C-sources for a few simple numerical analysis routines as well as the compiled output and the assembly files they generate.

Does anyone know of a decompiler (or a C->brainfuck translator) that could give me something akin to the "brainfuck source code"?

Comment: I agree fully with belisarius, and I don't think turning in machine-generated code counts as doing the homework assignment in any language you care to use. I would give you a bad grade if I were your instructor. :-)

Comment: @Sevenless Is the same. Just include a zipped version of the source file in the compiled version and you have a language de-compilable on the fly.

Comment: Just learn [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) or J :-) After all, those *are* "useful" languages.

Comment: You should write an answer in Postscript - the professor can run it on his laser printer.

Comment: Postscript is one of my favourite languages.

Comment: I just wanted to appropriately reply to someone who sent a birthday clock written in assembly ;). Anyway, this (http://esolangs.org/wiki/C2BF) might be helpful...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) or [J](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29).

Unlike BF, they were actually designed to serve a "useful" (and not a "useful as in BF" sense) purpose - and yet can easily make Perl code-golf entries look like novels. (The dedication and mental training to enjoy these languages is currently more than my skill/effort levels.)

If the goal is using a purely esoteric language, I have always enjoyed the look of [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) programs. It looks prettier and is actually able to [solve common CS homework problems](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet/samples.html). Following the links will reveal "Piet assemblers" and other tools. Win.

Happy coding.

Comment: Look at this one http://www.matthias-ernst.eu/piet/ ... a BF interpreter in Piet!

Comment: @belisarius Beautiful art -- I am not able to fathom the minds of other people :)

Comment: J is unbelievable. http://beust.com/weblog/2008/08/28/coding-challenge-wrap-up/

Answer (score 12):

For what it's worth, I just wrote a very simple Brainfuck Assembler (inspired by this SO post actually), which assembles readable source code (not C, just something simple and nameless) to BrainFuck. The source-code and compilation/usage instructions can be found here: [BrainFuck Assembler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/brainfuckassemb/).

Edit: The project has recently been updated under a new name: [BrainFix](http://brainfix.sourceforge.net).

Edit 2: I redid the entire project. The new and improved version has quite a lot of features and is available on [Github](https://github.com/jorenheit/brainfix).

Comment: i wanted to take a look, but ... given the current availability of sourceforge i would suggest to duplicate you work somewhere else too.

Comment: @philippelhardy It took me a few years but I took your advice, started from scratch and hosted it on github now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search brings up the (a?) [Brainfuck site](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/), which links to an [archive](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/) with "all things Brainfuck". I doubt there's a C->brainfuck translator anywhere, I wouldn't think anyone would invest that much time.